# Why does this regex [^\/]\d{4} not match a 4 digit number at the begining of a line?

Tags: .net, regex

The pattern `[^\/]\d{4}` works for `2014(i)` and `01/01/2015` but not `2014(i)` when it is the first item in the text file.

[Sample in regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5B%5E%5C%2F%5D%5Cd%7B4%7D&i=2012%201987%201943%20%0D%0A08%2F2015%204%2F2015%204%2F15%202012%20)

Comment: Check this `(?<![^\/])\d{4}` or `(?:^|[^\/])\d{4}`. You are looking for a character before digits and at the beginning of line / string there is no character.

Comment: The first part of the pattern, `[^\/]`, is matching the first digit - at which point there are only three digits left. That's why the pattern doesn't match. I haven't left this as an answer, as there's an implicit question of "how do I fix this" - and I don't know whether revo's suggestion is the best one for that or not. (I'm far from a regex expert.)

Comment: The (?<![^/])\d{4} matches if the first thing in the line is 2015 but not any other instances, and it also matches 01/01/2015.  Just trying to find 4 digits not preceeded by /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a *character* before digits and at the beginning of line / string there is no character right before them. As @JonSkeet mentioned in comments since no character before digits is found at beginning of a line, `[^\/]` consumes first digit so number of left digits doesn't match `\d{4}`. That said, you are looking for this:

```
(?<!\/)\d{4}
```

- `(?<!\/)` a [negative lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) which assures no `/` before digits (an assertion, no character consuming applies)

[**Live demo**](https://regex101.com/r/7E0R1v/1)

or if you have no problem with matching preceding character:

```
(?:^|[^\/])\d{4}
```